# When experimental search for exotic dark matter-like particles began exactly?

Tags: history, dark-matter, epistemology

I am looking for information about :

- **what was the first experiment that claimed to look specifically for non baryonic dark matter particles ;**
- **when occurred the first serious(*) reporting of an experimental result regarding a non baryonic dark matter candidate.**

(*: published in a peer reviewed journal)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first report of non-baryonic matter that I know was [Evidence for Detection of a Moving Magnetic Monopole, Phys. Rev. Lett. 35, 487–490 (1975)](http://prl.aps.org/abstract/PRL/v35/i8/p487_1). However I'd guess you were thinking of more conventional dark matter candidates, and the first remotely credible publication I know of was the [DAMA experiment](http://people.roma2.infn.it/~dama/web/home.html).

I should add that neither experiment is viewed as a definite detection of non-baryonic matter.

Comment: Thank you @John Rennie! I did not expect to encounter this particular ghost from the past. I have no institutional on-line access to the article unfortunately. Did the authors explicitly mention the magnetic monopole as a dark matter particle (in any astrophysical meaning)?